# Is it possible to solve a puzzle using lcm?

Tags: least-common-multiple

I was solving one programming puzzle, which says that:

*Somebody asks you how much competitors do you have and you answer that K part started with first problem, M with second, N with third while D think where to start. If it's true statement you should find number of competitors(S) or say that statement is incorrect.*

We can create an equation and solve it:

```
S/K + S/M + S/N + D = S
S = D * K * N * M / (K * N * M - N * M - K * M - K * N )
```

If `denominator <= 0` or `numerator % denominator <> 0` we can say that statement is incorrect, otherwise it's true.

I also assumed that I can solve this task using `lcm` in such a way:

```
S = lcm(lcm(K, N), M)
```

and if

```
S/K + S/N + S/M + D == S
```

than statement is correct, otherwise it's false.

But in this case I can't pass all the tests. Can you tell me if my assumption is incorrect?

Comment: I assume the competition has only 3 problems. In such case, LCM cannot be used here since D is a constant. The question statement "K part started with first problem, M with second, N with third" actually tells you that a certain fraction (0 <= x <= 1) of competitors has already started, so the remaining fraction (1 - x) of competitors are still thinking, and hence S(1 - x) = D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your equation for $S$:
$$S=\frac D{\left(1-\frac1K-\frac1N-\frac1M\right)}.$$

The first thing to check is that $S$ is an integer, which can be done with integer arithmetic exactly as you described.

If it *is* an integer, then you also have to check that each of $S/K$, $S/N$ and $S/M$ are integers, or equivalently that
$S \mathrm{\ mod\ } K$, $S \mathrm{\ mod\ } N$, and $S \mathrm{\ mod\ }  M$ are all zero.  This is the same as checking that $\mathrm{lcm}(K,N,M)$ divides $S$, so in principle you *can* do this part with lcm.

Comment: Be careful, after finding S we should also check S/K, S/N and S/M are all integers too. For example, if K=3, N=4, M=6, D=8, then S will be 32, but S/K and S/M are not integers. Surely you can't have 10.6667 competitors starting with the first problem?

Comment: Fair enough.  So ${\rm lcm}(K,N,M)$ must divide $D$.

Comment: @Tad I think you have problem in formula, it should be `S = D/(1-1/K-1/N-1/M)`, but I don't know markup language to edit it properly.

Comment: @Tad Also about _So lcm(K,N,M) must divide D_, if K=2,N=4,M=7,D=3 then lcm=28 and it won't divide D, but lcm is correct answer right now.

Comment: @viakondratiuk Sorry, I had a typo in the comment as well.  All should be fixed now.